# ios swift ResearchKit condition for skip with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nspredicate, researchkit

I am working on a small app using ResearchKit. Unfortunately I could not find enough examples to figure out how to skip a question based on the answer from a previous question.
I have put together the below code, which I know is not ok and not working.
I am looking for help to figure out what is not ok.

```
let textChoices2 = [

ORKTextChoice(text: "Answer 1", value: 0),

ORKTextChoice(text: "Answer 2", value: 1),

ORKTextChoice(text: "Answer 3", value: 2),

ORKTextChoice(text: "Answer 4", value: 3)
]

let questAnswerFormat2: ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat = ORKAnswerFormat.choiceAnswerFormatWithStyle(.SingleChoice, textChoices: textChoices2)

let questQuestionStep2 = ORKQuestionStep(identifier: "TextChoiceQuestionStep2", title: questQuestionStepTitle, answer: questAnswerFormat2)

//////////////////////////// Here I need help

let task: ORKNavigableOrderedTask = ORKNavigableOrderedTask(identifier: "xyz123", steps: steps)

//the identifier for ORKNavigableOrderedTask is a random number in my case, is it ok like this?

let resultSelector: ORKResultSelector = ORKResultSelector(stepIdentifier: "TextChoiceQuestionStep", resultIdentifier: "ImageChoiceQuestionStep”)

//stepIdentifier is the question based on which I decide if I want to skip the current question. Is it ok like this?

//resultIdentifier is the question to which I want to jump to. Is it ok like this?

let predicate: NSPredicate = ORKResultPredicate.predicateForChoiceQuestionResultWithResultSelector(resultSelector, expectedAnswerValue: "0”)

//expectedAnswerValue is the value of the answer for which I want to skip the current question. Is it ok like this?

let predicateRule: ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule = ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule(resultPredicatesAndDestinationStepIdentifiers:[ (predicate, "ImageChoiceQuestionStep") ])

//“ImageChoiceQuestionStep” from the row above is the question to which I want to jump to. Is it ok like this?

task.setNavigationRule(predicateRule, forTriggerStepIdentifier: "ImageChoiceQuestionStep”)

//“ImageChoiceQuestionStep” from the row above is the question to which I want to jump to. Is it ok like this?

questQuestionStep2.task = task
```

Comment: Since you seem a relatively new user, I thought worth mentioning that it's good StackOverflow etiquete to mark a suitable answer as accepted, so the question no longer shows as unanswered. If the answer is not satisfactory, you could comment on it requesting further clarification.

Comment: Thank you @RicardoSánchez-Sáez, you are right.
I also thank you for the patience with which you gave me an answer.
For the last few days I have been working on something else.
I'll soon get the chance to test what you explained me and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of a `resultSelector` ([docs](http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKResultSelector.html)) is to identify the exact result you want the predicate to match against. A `resultSelector` must have a `resultIdentifier`, which in *question steps* is both the identifier of the *question step* and the *question result* within (it is not the identifier of the step you want to jump to!).

Optionally, a `resultSelector` can have a `stepIdentifier` (when you want to match *form results*, several of whom can be contained in the same *step*) or a `taskIdentifier` (if you want to match a result in a previously completed task). I think you don't need these two for your use case.

Then, with a valid `resultSelector` pointing to your question of interest, you build a *result predicate*, and with the predicate you build an `ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule` which will have the `destinationStepIdentifier` (this is the step you want to jump to).

Finally, you attach the *predicate step navigation rule* to the step which must trigger the rule (which can be the same step being matched by the predicate, or a step that appears later in the task).

Once you have set everything up and you run the task, the *navigation rule* is triggered when you are leaving the step it is attached to, and the *destinationIdentifier* contained in the *navigation rule* points to the step you conditionally jump to.

See the [`TaskFactory.swift`](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/09e717c69f2fdb1bef034a2a8c64f70aa49aae26/Testing/ORKTest/ORKTest/TaskFactory.swift) file (which implements the *Navigable Ordered Task* item in the `ORKTest` example project) for a complete example on how to achieve conditional jumps on swift.

Also check the documentation on [`ORKNavigableOrderedTask`](http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKNavigableOrderedTask.html), [`ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule`](http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule.html) and [`ORKResultPredicate`](http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKResultPredicate.html) for further information.

I believe you can achieve what you want by using these.

---

Additionally, there's an ongoing [Pull Request](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/pull/636) which adds the concept of *skip navigation rules* to `ORKNavigableTask`, which may be more specifically suitable to your needs. But I suggest you grasp how the general navigation rules work first. Hopefully that PR will be merged soon.